# Why do I get two notifications for the same question?

Tags: support, notifications, moderators, per-site-meta

Since I am one of the moderators for *Drupal Answers*, I get notifications for every question asked on the meta site. Some minutes ago, I got two notifications for [the same question](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/is-it-appropriate-to-change-the-scope-of-a-question-with-a-bounty-on-it).

[image: screenshot]

I have checked, and there aren't two copies of the same question, nor does the question has an answer.

[image: screenshot]

There isn't a deleted question with that title too.

Is it a bug, or is there an explanation for this?

I think it happened before, but I didn't ask a question because it was the first and I thought it was an hic-up.

This doesn't happen in [the page showing all the notifications per questions, answers, and comments I get](https://stackexchange.com/users/79630/kiamlaluno?tab=inbox).

[image: screenshot]

If this depends from the browser, I am using Google Chrome 26.0.1410.65 running on OS X 10.8.3. The revision shown for the site is 2013.4.19.658.

Comment: Did you check if there's a _deleted_ version of the question? Sometimes people will post, delete and re-post. No idea why...

Comment: Whoops… I forgot about that. It's not this is the case, though.

Comment: For the record I only got that notification once

Comment: @Clive It must be because you are the second one who got the notification. `;)`